# Dimensions of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help starting with these questions. I'm confused on how to find the dimension of the following subespaces of matrices.

Question 1: Let $M_{3,3}$ be the vector space of all 3 × 3 matrices defined over $\mathbb{R}$. Calculate the dimension of the following subspaces of $M_{3,3}$

(a) $W = M_{3,3}.$

(b) $X = \{A ∈ M_{3,3} \ | \ A^T = A \}$ the set of all symmetric matrices.

(c) $Y = \{A ∈ M_{3,3} \ | \ A^T = −A \}$ the set of all skew-symmetric matrices.

(d) $Z = \{A ∈ M_{3,3} \ | \ AB = 0 \}$ where $B$ is the following matrix:

$$
B = \left(
\begin{matrix} 
0 & 1 &0 \\ 
0 &0 &1 \\
0 & 0& 0
\end{matrix}\right)$$

I managed to solve part (a) but for part (b) and (c), would a symmetric matrix be: 
\begin{matrix} 
a & b & c \\ 
b & d  &e \\
c & e & f
\end{matrix}
and since we need to know 6 elements thus the dimension will be 6?

and a skew matrix:
\begin{matrix} 
0 & b &c \\ 
-b &0 &d \\
-c & -d& 0
\end{matrix}
since we only need to know for b,c,d, thus the dimension will be 3?

> Please do correct me if I'm wrong in any of my explanation. Thank You :)

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. See [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).
Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: w.r.t. (b) and (c) you are right. Just continue to get a basis using matrices having 1 only at one specific position and zero elsewhere that satisfies the condition to be part of the corresponding subespace.

Comment: I see. Would the number basis then be the dimension of the matrix?

Comment: Yes, of course. The number of elements in any basis is the same and we call that number the dimension. You can prove that any two basis have the same cardinality (the number of elements of that set).

Answer (score 1):

For each pair $(i,j)$ with $1\leq i, j\leq3$ let $E_{i,j}$ be the matrix having 1 at position $(i,j)$ (row $i$ and column $j$) and zero elsewhere. So,
$$
E_{i,j}(r,s) = \delta_{i,r}\delta_{j,s} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if}\ i=r \ \text{and} \ j=s,\\ 
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
For (a) you can prove that the set of all possible $E_{i,j}$ matrices is a basis of $M_{3,3}$.

For (b) and (c) you have the right idea. You only need now a basis.

For (d) try to write in simple equations instead of matrices the condition $AB=0$, that is replace your $B$ matrix in the matrix equation and write then the conditions for a matrix to be in $Z$. Then try to find a basis using matrices $E_{i,j}$ being in $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the right intuition for questions (b) and (c). In particular, the dimension of the space of symmetric matrices is 6 (corresponding to the six independent parameters $a, b, c, d, e$ and $f$) and the dimension of the space of skew-symmetric matrices is $3$. You should relate this intuition to the actual definition of dimension by writing down basises for these spaces.

For the last question, you should notice that $AB=0$ just means that the first two columns of $A$ are zero, and apply similar logic.